# Line Integral from 0 to 1

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

I want to calculate the line integral of a function $f$ for the line from 0 to 1. We defined the line integral as $\int_\gamma f(t)dt=\int_a^b f(\gamma)\gamma'dt$ for a continuous $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$.

I have trouble understanding what exactly $\gamma$ is in my case. Obviously it's a continous function $[0,1]\to\mathbb C$, but how do I continue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\gamma$ refers to a parameterization of the curve along which you are integrating. Here, you are integrating along the line from $0$ to $1$, so you must parameterize this line. One parameterization of this line is
$$ \gamma(t) = t, \qquad 0 \leq t \leq 1.$$

Comment: Thanks, but there is one thing I don't quite understand still. Isn't the purpose of those line integrals to "walk across" the complex plane? So shouldn't this $\gamma$ be a vector? In this case $\gamma(t)=(t,0)^T$? If I would want to integrate from 1 to i, I would intuitively say that $\gamma=(-t,t)^T$ or something like that. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: If you were to integrate from $1$ to $i$, you might use the line $\gamma(t) = 1 + (i-1)t$.

Comment: @user424862 the complex number $1$ can be considered the "vector" $(1,0)$ just fine.

Comment: @mixedmath Okay, so let's say I plug that in: $\int_\gamma f(t)=\int_0^1 f((1+(i-1)t)\cdot(1-i)dt$ sounds a bit complicated to me for such an easy line. But it is correct, right? And the integral could be a complex number in the end?